# Ratio of students in two classrooms

Tags: probability, ratio

I would appreciate any help in solving this question:

Students in one classroom answer correctly with probability **greater than** 0.5. Students in the other classroom answer correctly with probability **less than** 0.5. Teacher answers correctly with probability **greater than** 0.5. Together they answer correctly with probability of **exactly** 0.5. What is the ratio of students in those two classrooms?

Comment: How many teachers are there? One for each classroom?

Comment: I think it is only one teacher and unknown numbers students in each class.

Comment: Teacher is the same for both classrooms.

Comment: Does "Together" include the first class?

Comment: It includes both classes and the teacher.
p(First class) > 0.5; 
p(Second class) < 0.5; 
p(Teacher) > 0.5; 
p(First class & Second class & Teacher) = 0.5;

Answer (score 0):

If there are $s_1$ students in the first class with a probability of $p_1$ each of being correct, and  $s_2$ students in the second class with a probability of $p_2$ each of being correct, and the teacher has a probability of $p_t$ of being correct, then *"Together they answer correctly with probability of exactly $0.5$"* suggests to me that any positive rational ratio of $s_1:s_2$ is possible.

For example for the ratio $a:b$ consider $$s_1=a, s_2=b, \; p_1=p_t=\frac12 +\frac{b}{2(a+b+1)} \gt \frac12, \;p_2= \frac{b}{2(a+b+1)} \lt \frac12.$$

This has $$\frac{\displaystyle a \left(\frac12 +\frac{b}{2(a+b+1)}\right) + b \left(\frac{b}{2(a+b+1)}\right) +\left(\frac12 +\frac{b}{2(a+b+1)}\right)}{a+b+1} =\frac{1}2.$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I believe it might be wrong to assume that probabilities of p1 and pt are same even though they are both greater than 0.5.

Comment: Having $p_1$ and $p_t$ different does not restrict the possible student ratios.  If the answer to the original question is not "anything" then there needs to be more information than supplied.

Comment: Thanks for the further elaboration. I run into this problem when I tested for software developer position in Microsoft. As far as I know tests are always straightforward, without "trick" questions. I assumed that I wasn't able to solve it because of my lack of knowledge in this field.